# elasticsearch-river-mongodb plugin script error

Tags: elasticsearch

There is an error when I move the data from mongodb to elasticsearch using elasticsearch-river-mongodb plugin.

The _river command is:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/ComponentUsageDataEntity/_meta" -d '
{
  "type":"mongodb",
  "mongodb":{
    "servers":[{"host":"corp.com","port":27017 }],
    "db":"udc","collection":"ComponentUsageDataEntity",
    "script":"ctx.document.user2 = ctx.document.user;"
  },
  "index":{
    "name":"udc","type":"ComponentUsageDataEntity"
  }
}'
```

The mongodb data look like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5146cf67e4b0015f31b25cad"),
  "user" : "Photoshop",
  "module" : "EASE Get Latest Codex Build Plugin",
  "comment" : "http://sj2slu348.corp.adobe.com:8088/",
  "collectDate" : ISODate("2013-03-18T08:25:11.601Z")
}
```

That is I try to rename `user` as `user2`, but It failed. It is seems that the script is incorrect, but I don't know the reason. 
The error message is `SCRIPT_IMPORT_FAILED`:

```
[2014-07-24 19:05:22,680][WARN ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.Indexer] failed to script process {id=51498345e4b0015f31b2692d, operation=i, document={ "_id" : { "$oid" : "51498345e4b0015f31b2692d"} , "user" : "easetest" , "module" : "EASE Cloud Plugin" , "comment" : "http://com:8080/" , "collectDate" : { "$date" : "2013-03-20T09:37:09.358Z"}}}, ignoring
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: script_lang not supported [js]
    at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.compile(ScriptService.java:143)
    at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.executable(ScriptService.java:151)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.Indexer.processBlockingQueue(Indexer.java:181)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.Indexer.run(Indexer.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install another Elasticsearch plugin : Lang-Javascript
Please find documentation here : https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-lang-javascript/